# install package on linux

Tags: packages, installing, algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

I downloaded ["algorithmicx" package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/) and I want to add it to my latex search path on debian. I use texmf-live with xetex. How I can do that?

Comment: See for example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#Installing_packages_manually